# Shortest path to find a highway

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I remember this as a classic problem, but all Google results are video-game-related, so I guess I should ask it here:

An adventurer got lost in the desert, but he knew that there was a highway exactly 10 miles from him. What path should he follow in order to find the highway as fast as possible (on average)?

Assumptions: (1) The adventurer would find the highway when his path intersects with it. (2) The speed of the adventurer is constant.

And what about the high-dimensional case, where the adventurer is lost in a n-dimensional space trying to find a (n-1)-dimensional superplane?

My guess for the 2D case is an Archimedean spiral but I can't prove it. For higher dimensional cases it seems really hard and I've no idea.

Thanks!

Comment: These are [sometimes called "lost in a forest" problems](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LostinaForestProblem.html), where the goal is to reach the boundary of a region.  In your case the region to escape from is a half-plane, but you know the distance to the boundary.

Comment: Why would you use spiral if you know that you can't find highway in less that 10 miles? Walking 10 miles straight then turning and making a perfect circle of radius 10 miles is certainly shorter.

Comment: The survey paper "Lost in a Forest" by [Finch and Wetzel (MAA Oct. 2004)](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Finch645-654.pdf) traces this problem to Bellman (1956).  While a best worst-case solution (minimax) is known, due to Isbell (1957), the authors say "[l]ittle is known... for other interpretations of 'best'."  This seems to include the best average case as unknown at the time of their writing.